# Why doesn't the daemon program exit without join()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, multiprocessing, daemon

The answer might be right in front of me on the link below but I still don't understand.  I'm sure after someone explains this to me, Darwin will be making a call to me.

The example is [at this link here](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#daemon-processes), although I've made some changes to try to experiment and help my understanding.

Here's the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def daemon():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting: ', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'Exiting: ', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()

def non_daemon():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    print 'Starting: ', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(6)
    print 'Exiting: ', p.name, p.pid
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = multiprocessing.Process(name='daemon', target=daemon)
    d.daemon = True

    n = multiprocessing.Process(name='non-daemon', target=non_daemon)
    n.daemon = False

    d.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    n.start()
#    d.join()
```

And the output of the code is:

```
Starting:  daemon 6173
Starting:  non-daemon 6174
Exiting:  non-daemon 6174
```

If the join() at the end is uncommented, then the output is:

```
Starting:  daemon 6247
Starting:  non-daemon 6248
Exiting:  daemon 6247
Exiting:  non-daemon 6248
```

I'm confused b/c the sleep of the daemon is 2 sec, whereas the non-daemon is 6 sec.  Why doesn't it print out the "Exiting" message in the first case?  The daemon should have woken up before the non-daemon and printed the message.

The explanation from the site is as such:

> The output does not include the “Exiting” message from the daemon
>   process, since all of the non-daemon processes (including the main
>   program) exit before the daemon process wakes up from its 2 second
>   sleep.

but I changed it such that the daemon should have woken up before the non-daemon does.  What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm using python 2.7 but apparently this problem is also in python 3.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a fun one to track down. The docs are somewhat misleading, in that they describe the non-daemon processes as if they are all equivalent; the existence of any non-daemon process means the process "family" is alive. [But that's not how it's implemented.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#l303) The parent process is "more equal" than others; `multiprocessing` registers an `atexit` handler that does the following:

```
for p in active_children():
    if p.daemon:
        info('calling terminate() for daemon %s', p.name)
        p._popen.terminate()

for p in active_children():
    info('calling join() for process %s', p.name)
    p.join()
```

So when the main process finishes, it *first* `terminate`s all `daemon` child processes, *then* `join`s all child processes to wait on non-`daemon` children and clean up resources from `daemon` children.

Because it performs cleanup in this order, a moment after your non-`daemon` `Process` `start`s, the main process begins cleanup and forcibly `terminate`s the `daemon` `Process`.

Note that fixing this can be as simple as `join`ing the non-`daemon` process manually, not just `join`ing the `daemon` process (which defeats the whole point of a `daemon` completely); that prevents the `atexit` handler from being called, delaying the cleanup that would `terminate` the `daemon` child.

It's arguably a bug (one that seems to exist up through 3.5.1; I reproed myself), but whether it's a behavior bug or a docs bug is arguable.

Comment: I've decided this constitutes a bug since the behavior differs from `threading` (which `multiprocessing` is supposed to emulate using processes instead of threads), where daemon threads keep running while _any_ non-daemon thread remains alive (main or otherwise). Opened [bug #26633](https://bugs.python.org/issue26633).

Comment: thx for going above and beyond in investigating this issue.  Glad to hear I'm not crazy and Darwin won't be calling for me, at least this time =)